# Where does grub-mkconfig get the UUID for root?

Tags: debian, grub

When I run `grub-mkconfig` on Debian 10, it generates something like:

```
...
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  fc6c3fbf-8cfc-411c-ac5d-072c6e8c8092
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fc6c3fbf-8cfc-411c-ac5d-072c6e8c8092
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-9-amd64 root=UUID=e0674dbf-3546-4898-9933-c9eb55703cb5 ro single
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-9-amd64
...
```

What is being done in this piece of the program and why does it use different UUIDs? And where are these UUIDS taken from?

Answer (score 2):

These are the UUIDs for two file systems `/` and `/boot`.

The first section tells grub how to find the `/boot` partition containing the Linux Kernel (and initramfs):

```
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  fc6c3fbf-8cfc-411c-ac5d-072c6e8c8092
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fc6c3fbf-8cfc-411c-ac5d-072c6e8c8092
    fi
```

The next section tells grub to boot Linux, passing the root kernel parameter which controls the file system it uses as `/`:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-9-amd64 root=UUID=e0674dbf-3546-4898-9933-c9eb55703cb5 ro single
```

---

I've never investigated how it finds them but ultimately they are controlled by `/etc/fstab`.  It's worth noting that if you change fstab to point to a different `/` or `/boot` you should always run this after as root:

```
update-grub
```